# Multiple Regression with Categorical Variables - How to evaluate the Omitted Values?

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to learn how to do multiple regression with categorical variables. I have a dataset of credit card balance data that looks as follows:

[image]

I then did a regression on all variables (in R):

[image]

I understand the concept of dummy variables and always omitting one of them, which R does for you automatically.

I haven't tried to optimize this model yet. But, I can see that GenderFemale is not statistically significant in predicting `Balance`. What I'd like to know is this. How can I determine if perhaps GenderMale is significant? Since Male was the variable omitted, how can I evaluate the significance of this variable?

Comment: What it shows is that the predicted mean for women is not different from the predicted mean for men. So the predicted mean for men is obviously not different from the predicted mean for women.

Comment: @mdewey - What if I had a situation where there was a statistical difference between genders? How would the output change so I would know this?

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of any categorical coefficient in linear regression such as this is *there is a difference in the average predicted dependent variable between the category and the omitted category, with a size of the coefficient*. Using this data, females have a *non-significant* average predicted balance of 9.55 less than males, controlling for the other covariates.

Since this is a difference between the categories, changing the omitted category would give the exact same non-significant result, with a flipped ($+$) sign. Males will have +9.55 more than females.

If you want to test this on your data (I can't use the data given since it's not reproducible) you can change the omitted (reference) category of any `factor` in R using the `relevel()` function:

```
caseStudyData2$Gender <- relevel(caseStudyData2$Gender, ref = "Female")
```

And run the model again.

Comment: This makes sense. Would there ever be a situation where the included category is non significant but the excluded would be significant? I don't see how this might be possible, but just curious.

Comment: There can be with more than 2 levels, because each level will show the difference between them and the reference category, but the difference between them might very well be different. When only two categories exist, there shouldn't be any differences.

Comment: So if I have a categorical variable with say three levels and two show as not being significant, how can I determine if the reference category is or isn't (without rerunning the model and choosing a different reference category)?

Comment: Not really. you can get a general idea by looking at the difference between the categories. In your case, you see that in Ethnicity a gap of 16 is non significant (between Asian and the reference category). The difference between Caucasian and Asian is about 7 (16-9) so it should not be significant no matter which is your reference category (bearing in mind that significance is a matter of the std.error as well as the effect size, so one cant be sure)